Proof correction Pinsker's Inequality:
I want to show Pinsker's Inequality:
Let $P$ and $Q$ be probability. Suppose  $P \ll Q$. Then,
$$
\| P - Q \|_{\mathrm{TV}} \leq \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{2} D_{\mathrm{KL}}(P \mid Q)}.
$$
For the proof, I have:
Since $P \ll Q$, the Radon-Nikodym derivative $u = \dfrac{dP}{dQ}$ exists and is a non-negative, $Q$-measurable function satisfying $\int_{\mathcal{X}} u \, dQ = 1$.
The total variation distance can be expressed as
\begin{align}
    \|  P - Q \| _{\mathrm{TV}} = \dfrac{1}{2} \int_{\mathcal{X}} | u - 1 | \, dQ.
\end{align}
Similarly, the Kullback-Leibler divergence is
\begin{align}
D_{\mathrm{KL}}(P \mid Q) = \int_{\mathcal{X}} u \log u \, dQ.
\end{align}
Assume the following inequality holds $ \forall u > 0$:
\begin{align}
| u - 1 | \leq \sqrt{2 ( u \log u - u + 1 )}.
\end{align}
Integrating both sides with respect to $Q$, yields
\begin{align}
    \int_{\mathcal{X}} | u - 1 | \, dQ \leq \int_{\mathcal{X}} \sqrt{2 ( u \log u - u + 1 )} \, dQ.
\end{align}
Applying Jensen's inequality for the concave function $f(t) = \sqrt{t}$ gives
$$
\int_{\mathcal{X}} \sqrt{2 ( u \log u - u + 1 )} \, dQ \leq \sqrt{ 2 \int_{\mathcal{X}} ( u \log u - u + 1 ) \, dQ }.
$$
Simplifying the integral on the right, yields
$$
\int_{\mathcal{X}} ( u \log u - u + 1 ) \, dQ = D_{\mathrm{KL}}(P \parallel  Q) - \int_{\mathcal{X}} u \, dQ + 1 = D_{\mathrm{KL}}(P \mid Q) - 1 + 1 = D_{\mathrm{KL}}(P \mid Q).
$$
Therefore, we get
$$
\int_{\mathcal{X}} | u - 1 | \, dQ \leq \sqrt{2 D_{\mathrm{KL}}(P \parallel  Q)}.
$$
from which follows the result.
Can this be done in this way. I am not sure if for the inequality\begin{align}
| u - 1 | \leq \sqrt{2 ( u \log u - u + 1 )}.
\end{align}
u can be 0.
I would appreciate any suggestions.
